# Activation key part number for Db2 Data Server Client 11.5?

Tags: windows, ibm, db2

I think I have reached the end of Google, but still not able to find the part number I need to download the license file for IBM Data Server Client 11.5. Not listed here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-version-111-activation-key-part-numbers and I start to get tired of the message

> LIC1407N  You are trying to register an invalid license certificate file

**Update**

The client will be serving a set of .Net applications hosted on IIS. They are dependent on the db2 catalog konfig 'test' (and 'prod'). The db2 catalog commands is successfully, but when I want to verify the connection to db2 using command

```
db2 connect to TEST user TESTUSER
```

I get (when applying the valid password)

```
SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a
licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968
```

If I type a password I know is wrong I get

```
D:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2 connect to TEST user TESTUSER
Enter current password for CFFSAFI:
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR
PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

So the first error with correct password and the last one with the wrong, to my knowledge it confirmes that I'm able to connect to db2

Which is explained here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql1598n-error-connecting-mainframe-db2-ibm-data-server-driver-even-though-db2-connect-license-file-exists-license-directory-install-path (I do not have a license file in the path)

```
D:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2licm.exe -l
Product name:                     "IBM Data Server Client"
Product identifier:               "db2client"
Version information:              "11.5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, as explained here [SQL1598N error connecting to mainframe DB2 from IBM Data Server Driver even though DB2 Connect license file exists in the license directory of the install path](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql1598n-error-connecting-mainframe-db2-ibm-data-server-driver-even-though-db2-connect-license-file-exists-license-directory-install-path)

> It is possible to license the IBM Data Server Driver to connect to mainframe DB2 such as DB2 for z/OS, IBM DB2 for IBM i, and DB2 Server for VM and VSE servers by copying one of these files into the installation_path/license directory.
>
> - DB2 Connect Personal Edition: db2conpe.lic
> - DB2 Connect Application Server Edition: db2consv_as.lic
> - DB2 Connect Enterprise Edition: db2consv_ee.lic
> - DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System i: db2consv_is.lic
> - DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z: db2consv_zs.lic

I did as explained, found the activation key for IBM DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z - Activation 11.5 for Linux, UNIX and Windows Multilingual whic is *CC1V0ML* and downloaded it and added it - restartet and voila

```
D:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2 connect to TEST user TESTUSER
Enter current password for TESTUSER:

Database Connection Information

Database server        = DB2 z/OS 11.1.5
SQL authorization ID   = TESTUSER
Local database alias   = TESTUSER
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to apply any license to a Db2 client. Db2 Clients are not licensed.

Comment: I added some more details, see "update"